# how to filter svn export

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, visual-sourcesafe

I want to get only specific files using `svn command line` utlity.

I've a batch script that gets only specific files from `vss`, using `ss` tool of `vss`.

In `vss`the command is:

```
ss get *.c
```

I need similar functionality with `svn` command utility.
How can I start ?

Comment: you want to exexute ss over all files with `vss` extension?

Comment: No, I want to retrieve specific files of interest from svn using svn command utility recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like, get the file list which are matching some extension, like .txt or .c.

`svn list -R http://svn/url/till/the/path/you/need/ | grep ".extension"`

Then for every line in the output of the above command use `svn export` to get the files in your local machine.

Edit:

> repository=`http://svn/url/till/the/path/need/`
>
> $target_directory=some path in machine
>
> for line in `svn list -R http://svn/url/till/the/path/need/ | grep ".extension"`
>   do
>
> ```
>   filename=`echo "$line" |sed "s|$repository||g"`
>
>   if [ ! -d $target_directory$filename ]; then
>      directory=`dirname $filename`
>     mkdir -p $target_directory$directory
>    svn export --force -r HEAD $repository$line $target_directory$filename --username abc --password password123
> ```
>
> fi
>
> done

Comment: How to store the result and access each entry? If I use `export` on the result, would the files be retrieved recursively ?